# I want to tokenize a text and also want to consider space and new line as separate tokens: for NLP Task

Tags: natural-language-processing

I want to tokenize a text and also want to consider space and new line as separate tokens:

if there are multiple spaces, then tokenize them separately, for example, "Hi, I am\n  Teddy" this should tokenize as ["Hi"," ", ","," ","I"," ","am","\n"," "," ","Teddy"]

**Note: That After new-line (\n) in text there are 2 spaces**

Answer (score 1):

```
def tokenize_text(text):
    return re.findall(r'\S+|\n|\s', text.replace('\n\n', '\n \n'))
```

This gives the tokenization of text, including space and new-line